# If R is a regular language, is $R^3= R \circ R \circ R$ also regular?

Tags: regular-languages

My understanding of a regular language is that for a language to be formal, it must be able to be represented by a DFA or NFA. To prove a language is not regular you can use the pumping lemma to get a contradiction.

I am trying to figure out whether $R^3$ or $R \circ R \circ R$ is regular if R is also regular.

My understanding of the definition of $R \circ R$ is that it is kind of a transitive mapping of R?

And I think if $R \circ R$ is regular then $R \circ R \circ R$ is also regular, so I need to prove $R \circ R$ is regular which really means that I am trying to prove that regular languages are transitive?

I am not sure how I would go about doing this as I am a little confused how regular languages and transitivity relate - as I have only worked with relations for transitivity.

Comment: I have no idea what R o R is. I suggest you find out the definition.

Comment: By "o" you mean $\cdot$, i.e. concatination? If yes then there is nothing to prove if you define regular languages with regular expressions. With finite automata it is a simple exercise to construct from two NFAs $\mathcal{A}_1, \mathcal{A}_2$ an automaton whose language is $L(\mathcal{A}_1) \cdot L(\mathcal{A}_2)$.

Comment: Sorry, I must have been misinformed on what I saw. I had lecture slides using the 'o' for compositions of relations so got a bit confused when I saw this. Thank you for your explanation :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'$R$' 
 is not used in the literature to indicate languages ​​... generally we use $L$.
Anyway, the "$\circ$" operator indicates the concatenation of two or more languages. Keep in mind that the concatenation of regular languages is also regular: you can proove this by 'linking' the *NFA*'s/*DFA*'s thath recognize them.
In this case you are concatenating a regular language with itself, so the resulting language is also regular.

NB: 
The opposite is not always true: if the concatenation of two languages ​​is regular, this does not mean that the languages ​​themselves are necessarily regular.

Comment: Thanks for your great response! Just a follow up question: if I have something like quad(L)={wwww | w ∈ L} where quad(L) is a language transformer function, and L is a regular language, does that mean quad(L) is also regular?

Comment: @DoubleRainbowZ you can use the pumping lemma for regular languages to prove e.g. that quad((a+b)^*) is not regular, so your transformer function does not preserve regularity. This is an easy exercise if you understand and can apply the pumping lemma.

Comment: So it would be something like ((a+b)^p)((a+b)^p)((a+b)^p)((a+b)^p), then you pump up, and so it becomes ((a+b)^(p+i))((a+b)^p)((a+b)^p)((a+b)^p) and thus is no longer regular correct?